# It is possible to obtain the last wall publications of a programatically given Facebook user without registering my app on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

i need to achieve that, show the last wall publications of a programatically given user.

But i need to do it without login on facebook, and without using Oauth, **without registering my app on facebook.**

It is possible? i can't find the way to do it :S

Answer (score 1):

To get any user information from Facebook you will need to create an application.  To get private user data such as their last wall post, they will need to be logged into Facebook and authenticate with your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few things you can get without an access token from the user. It also depends on what security the user has set up. I don't know the reasons for not registering your app but its a simple process.

User Object
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

You can use the following to get the public feed https://graph.facebook.com/markzuckerberg/feed

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it sounds like you want to get data from the Facebook API without using the Facebook API. This is not going to work very well.

You could access a user's posts, if their visibility was set to Public, using any access token (e.g. one you create using the [Graph Explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)) but without knowing the user's uid, how will you know which user's posts to request?

Realistically you need them to authorise your app before you can get their uid, and by that time you could just use that same authorisation to access their public posts without needing any 'hacky' workarounds.